# Using the maven-remote-resources-plugin and specifying the resourcesDirectory

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-remote-resources

I'm trying to override the default resources directory (src/main/resources) when using the *maven-remote-resources-plugin*. However the specified value in the sample below doesn't seem to be taken into account.  Would appreciate if someone could give me some pointers.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.resource.library</groupId>
    <artifactId>resource-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>ResourceLibrary</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bundle</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <resourcesDirectory>${basedir}/common</resourcesDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

EDIT: I'm wondering if this is a bug in the plugin, since I see the following in the DEBUG output of the build, which implies that its attempting to use the correct resources directory.  Nothing else relevant appears in the debug output.

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:bundle' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) includes = [**/*]
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = C:\jit\workspace\ResourceLibrary\target\classes
[DEBUG]   (f) resourcesDirectory = C:\jit\workspace\ResourceLibrary\common
```

EDIT: I think this may actually be a bug so have raised: [MRRESOURCES-96](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRRESOURCES-96)

Comment: Not that this is the reason, but [`basedir` is deprecated in favor of `project.basedir.`](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3-LATEST/maven-model-builder/#Model_Interpolation)

Comment: Have you tried to add a file extension in `<include>?`

Comment: @GeroldBroser thanks for the heads up on [project.basedir](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3-LATEST/maven-model-builder/#Model_Interpolation).  I've just tried the following includes, but none of them appear to work: `common.txt`, `**/*.txt`, `*.txt`.

Comment: Can you supply the output of the build?

Comment: @GeroldBroser I've added some of the DEBUG output from the build to my original post.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need maven-remote-resources-plugin?

If your goal is to `override the default resources directory` ,then you can use [mvn resources:copy-resources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html), since it's more flexible. An example [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html).

**Alternative**

You can also use the `resources` goal provided by resources plugin, and specify the resources in pom file's  block. Example [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html).

---

Edit

About maven-remote-resources-plugin, see the [usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/usage.html) page:

> This will trigger the scanning of that project's $basedir/src/main/resources directory and create the $basedir/target/classes/META-INF/maven/remote-resources.xml manifest file.

That means this plugin will create the `remote-resources.xml` file, but it doesn't mean that it will copy the resources for you.

I created an empty maven project using your plugin configuration, and it actually did create an remote-resources.xml file. Also, it did not copy the files under ${basedir}/common

To do that, just specify the resources in build section. Example:

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/common</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bundle</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <resourcesDirectory>${basedir}/common</resourcesDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I'm using the remote resources plugin because I want to be able to pool resources into a single project that can be included by other projects.

Comment: The [bundle](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/bundle-mojo.html) goal seems to imply that the plugin should be including those resources: "Bundle up resources that should be considered as a remote-resource."

Comment: @JiteshVassa By default it **does** include the resources, it just includes the resources in **src/main/resources** directory, as specified in [goal overview](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/). However, this behavior is not driven by this plugin per se. In your case, you want it to include resources in `${basedir}/common`, so you need to add extra behavior by utilising <resources> the way I presented.   PS, some plugins do allow you to specify the resources you want to copy, like copy-resources. I think this one just doesn't do that.

Comment: The name "resourcesDirectory" and its [description](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/bundle-mojo.html#resourcesDirectory) make people think that it would copy the resources. But it doesn't. So one can argue that it is a bug.

Answer (score -1):

kly is right about it not copying resources for you (I apologize, I cannot comment yet - not enough reputation).

With the "bundle" goal, you are only generating a manifest with a list of the included resources.  The manifest must be packaged in an artifact along with the resources themselves, which will only happen in your instance if you also use copy-resources to put them in the target/classes directory.

You then must use the "process" goal, and list your bundle, in any other project you wish to use the resources from.